# Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am sending email in reset password where everything is working fine.

My credentials are true though i am not able to send mail.

Its throwing error like

> Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
>   Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated"

here is my .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp-mail.outlook.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=foo@bar.com 
MAIL_PASSWORD=pass 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Thanks.

Comment: remove your real credential from the question

Comment: suggest you to change your current password as you posted it publically

Comment: Thanks ... i have changed it @ChetanAmeta

Comment: Please suggest me what to do i am getting that error. @ChetanAmeta

Comment: have a look at http://www.mailenable.com/kb/Content/Article.asp?ID=me020032&SS=